SignalR client fails to connect in Xamarin Forms
I am having a Xamarin Forms project and an ASP.Net Core webservice. I am using Conveyor by Keyoti Visual Studio Extension to access webservice from my android device. When I call hubConnection.StartAsync();, from Xamarin client override Task OnConnectedAsync() is called on the chathub webservice, but connection on the Xamarin Forms client fails giving an exception "The operation was canceled".
When OnConnectedAsync() is called on the server side, it should mean that the connection was established, but it fails on Xamarin side and hubconnection state is still Disconnected.
I have installed these Nuget packages:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client v8.0.5 For Xamarin Forms Client
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core v1.1.0 For ASP.Net Core Server
Here's my Xamarin Forms code:
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(url, (opts) =>
        {
            opts.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (message) =>
            {
                if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                    // bypass SSL certificate
                    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                return message;
            };
        })
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();

    hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) => { var finalMessage = $"{user} says {message}"; });

    Connect();
}

async Task Connect()
{
    try
    {
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();  // I get an Exception The operation was cancelled when this is called
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    try
    {
        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", user, message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // send failed
    }
}

Here's my ASP.Net Core webservice code:
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // This method is called on server side, but still connection fails on client side
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
}

public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
    return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}

public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}

I have also added services.AddSignalR(); and endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub"); in Startup.cs. As I have mentioned, when I call hubConnection.StartAsync(); from Xamarin client, OnConnectedAsync() is being called on Chathub service. But connection fails on client side and exception occurs 'The operation was canceled'. Any help would be much appreciated.

Hi Junaid, may I know you are using http or https ?

Because the latest android does not support HTTP requests by default.

@JasonPan, But i do not have latest android. I am testing on Android Marshmallow and another device having Android 10. Previously it was working successfully, but now it isn't working.

Ok, then we have to enable signalr client/server side logging to check what happened.
